# Android SSL Connection to Tomcat (self signed certificate) SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: android, ssl, https, tomcat7

I'm currently trying to implement a ssl connection in a simple testapp.

Setup: 
Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 with Tomcat 7
Internal Network IP: 192.168.189.42
Tomcat SSL:

```
https://192.168.177.42:8443/
```

SSL certificate created via: [Tomcat Tutorial](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration)
Device: API23 Tablet VM (Hyper-V, Visual Studio)
IDE: Android Studio

First I tested a ssl connection to Google via AsyncTask:

```
URL url = new URL("https://google.de");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
in.close();
```

Which works fine.

So i extracted the certificate from keystore with this command:

```
keytool -export -alias tomcat -file server.cer -keystore .keystore
```

I put that file into: myproject/res/raw/server.cer

In another AsyncTask I used the [sample code](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) from google developers to create a connection:

```
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server));
        Certificate ca;

        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);

        Log.d("CERT: ", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());

        caInput.close();

        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        URL url = new URL("https://192.168.177.42:8443/");
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        in.close();
```

if i try to execute this code i get the following Exception:

```
11-13 18:39:02.508  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.177.42 not verified:
11-13 18:39:02.508  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ certificate: sha1/wFJI0CzwVvJ2MuGvpoJaFO8y4z8=
11-13 18:39:02.508  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ DN: CN=Alcardis,OU=AL,O=AL,L=test,ST=state,C=XX
11-13 18:39:02.508  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ subjectAltNames: []
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:120)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at moe.testapp.TomcatWebservice.doInBackground(TomcatWebservice.java:64)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at moe.testapp.TomcatWebservice.doInBackground(TomcatWebservice.java:28)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-13 18:39:02.509  12135-12280/moe.testapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't understand how the host can not be verified. The certificate is read in correctly (i can at least access it in debugger with correct values) and the android app can also access the tomcat via https in the standard web browser.

---

Ok from the answer with comments i got some insightand  tried another aproach.
The Server has no FQDN and an the CN should equal FQND which is why it does not work in above code.

Because the Server does not have a FQDN I searched for an alternative way to use the ip address. I found this [howto](http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm) and created a certificate without CN but with alternativ names and put the ip in there also i had to add the line `keystoreType="PKCS12"` to the server.xml of tomcat because I changed from the default keystore to PKCS12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for SSL certificates is for a client to verify that the server name matches that in the certificate. This helps prevent man-in-the-middle attacks and server spoofing. When your server does not have a name (192.168.x.x), there can be no verification. For your initial application, you can turn off this verification.

You should leave server name verification on for any real application.

Comment: Indeed, the CN doesn't match the FQDN. But to solve the issue properly a new server certificate should be generated with the correct CN, and for more flexibiliy, the _**SAN field(subjectAltNames)**_ could be used as well.

Comment: The server don't has a name even in the real network is it possible to put an ip as name?

Comment: @Alcardis: you can put an IP into a certificate but depending on the client it must be in CN (most but not Safari), dNSName in SAN section (IE) or iPAddress in SAN section (most but not IE). Best put it in all these places :(

Comment: Ok it works now i created a new certificate without CN but with v3_req extension that allows alternative names. Question: is that secure?